# Interplanetary Taxi Orbit

Tags: orbital-mechanics

I would like to know the feasibility of an interplanetary "bus" or "taxi" which moves between, say, Earth-Mars or Earth-Venus without entering the orbit of either.  The idea is that the taxi is large--more like a roving space station.  It would have thick, heavy shielding to reduce radiation exposure to Earth-surface levels, enough interior volume to maintain full greenhouses to feed, say, dozens of people indefinitely, and full life support systems for recycling water, CO2, etc.

Travelers would need a conventional rocket/spacecraft to rendezvous and dock with the taxi, but the launch/land vehicle only needs enough life support to meet up with the taxi and then hop off at the destination.  Clearly, the taxi would need to move at a velocity within the delta-v budget of the launch vehicles, even though it could theoretically take an arbitrarily large time to accelerate to any desired velocity.

I realize that such a taxi would be immensely expensive and difficult to build.  I'm not really concerned with the economics.  I'm more interested in whether there is a feasible "orbit" or long-term trajectory with minimal burns which achieves the greatest number of visits between the two planets for a given solar orbit.  It would be great if the taxi could use gravity assist at the destination planet for any course changes to the next destination.  Obviously, an Earth-slingshot will not be feasible if the taxi has to get close to the atmosphere.

This "orbit" is less time-efficient than a one-shot trip because the taxi is moving continuously between the planets, and so one cannot choose an optimal alignment between them.  Even so, I would hope that the average trip would not be too much slower than the alternatives.  If a burn is required to shoot for the next destination, what is approximate fuel requirement?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars_cycler

Comment: Wow! That should be the answer, but I can't mark your comment.

Comment: It's perfectly fine to answer your own question. If you'd like to write a short summary of the article as an answer, please do so. And welcome to space!

Comment: There might be a interplanetary cycler answer here already...